# Send file in a post request in php

Tags: php

By using micro services i need to upload csv file which is accepting post http method. I tried uploading using postman but i am receiving error "request is not a multipart request"

Headers I am sending is

```
accept: application/json
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
```

Comment: it will be hard to tell where the error is without seeing a single line of code

Comment: Can you suggest me what should i pass in header to upload a file from the postman?

Comment: You missed the `boundary`: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; bondary=...`

Comment: File upload example in `php` https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm